# rails https routes for single controller gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, https, runtime-error

I am trying to secure single controller actions. for this, I did changes in routes  `resources :facilities, constraints: { :protocol => "https" }` to make it https URL. but when I fired link https://localhost:3000/facilities  it gives me error on browser ->

> SSL connection error

and on terminal I can see log like

> [2015-10-27 11:34:00] ERROR bad Request-Line
>   `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03/däo,��\x1C�B\x02%>\x01�I*����p�O\e�\x00Z�\x17Q\x00\x00\x1A�+�/\x00��'.
>   [2015-10-27 11:34:00] ERROR bad URI`H�{�\x1F�\x00\x00\x1A�+�/\x00��'.
>   [2015-10-27 11:34:00] ERROR bad Request-Line
>   `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x02��T�"�ptj"���1�ʗF�\x10�Զ�kK�`���c\x00\x00\x14V\x00�'.
>   [2015-10-27 11:34:00] ERROR bad Request-Line
>   `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x01\x10\x10�YO\x1F.��5A\x0Fh�Z.��Ë%��z�L\x06�ߪ�T\x00\x00\x14V\x00�'.

I dont know what is wrong with this?  or is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You can't access https from you local . you need to deploy it on server.

Comment: Thanks ... As u said I did routes changes on server too but still browser says 'SSL connection error'

Comment: did you setup SSL Certificates on server.

Comment: yes I did... I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html this link to create self signed certificate

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by config.force_ssl = true. Even if you remove that, which you may not want, you might still have issues with WEBrick giving you this error. You could try clearing cookies, but that still might not work.

A better alternative, if it's an option for you, would be to switch to using the thin server:

```
group :development do
   gem "thin"
end
```

Then:

```
$ bundle
$ thin start --ssl
```

I try this on my machine and it works fine with me . Hope this helps you too.

Comment: thanks ....this might work on local machine (on my machine its not working)..... But I am trying to do it on server having Apache server but still its not working